# InputStream won't read images in Runnable JAR

Tags: java, image, imageview, inputstream, runnable-jar

I'm writing a character builder for D&D, but I find myself in a weird situation, since InputStream class seems to work for certain files, then I do get: *java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null*

I am using the InputStream to load a javafx Image constructon into an ImageView constructor 
[new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(..)))];
It works when I'm loading some .jpeg images, but it doesn't when I do the same process on .png images

I've tryed many solutions described here on StackOverflow, but none seemed to get too close to my issue or to help at all:

> - creating a Source folder and retrieving the images from there
> - moving the image files to the class package
> - reading all the possible documentation

This piece of code works fine, which basically reads the images and puts them as background for some buttons

```java
ImageView imv;
        for(int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
            imv = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/ButtonImages/" + i + ".jpeg")));
...
```

and this is the build result (works on the JAR as it works on Eclipse)
[image: build result]

Then this piece of code, should load all the D&D races images

```java
this.imv = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/RaceImages/" + displayname + ".png")));
```

And it actually does show uplike this in Eclipse, but reports the error down there on the Runnable jar
[image: eclipse build]

This is an image of how my Project is structured.

[image: code structure]

This is what I am expecting to happen when I execute my Runnable JAR
[image: expectancy]

and this is what I get:

```
C:\Users\*****\Desktop>java -jar Dnd.jar
Width: 1238.6666666666667       Height: 720.0
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image.Image.validateInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at dnd.userinterface.javafx.scene.CharactersPane.<init>(CharactersPane.java:55)
        at dnd.userinterface.javafx.scene.DndPane.bookPane(DndPane.java:199)
        at dnd.userinterface.javafx.scene.DndPane.initPane(DndPane.java:99)
        at dnd.userinterface.javafx.scene.DndPane.<init>(DndPane.java:70)
        at dnd.userinterface.javafx.application.DNDApplication.start(DNDApplication.java:52)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

Which explicitly says that I am getting a null InputStream while reading the race images

**Note:** I actaully extracted the RaceImages folder where the jar is located, and running it through command line only (not the solution I'd ever want), runs the application
[image: Ambiguous Method]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the issue with a try-catch and I feel ashamed for not doing that earlier.

Eventually, the only mistake was a single capital letter in the name of a picture that was bypassed by Eclipse, but led to NullPointerException when running from .jar.

I deem this as resolved, and **no further intervention is needed**.

Here's a picture showing the issue

[image: error]

Comment: The joys of Windows - ignoring upper and lower case differences in file paths.

Answer (score 0):

If your images are in the `src/img/<whatever>` folder then your path should be `/img/<whataver>`.
Important is that you either build your jar (which is a zip file effectively) so that the image entries have the path in the code or you look into your jar file (e.g. whith 7zip) and correct your image paths in the code accordingly.

Comment: As stated in this picture  (https://i.epvpimg.com/YmlKeab.png), the Images are not stored in src, but in imgs